telegram python API to send multiple pictures in one post
async def send_photos(bot_token, chat_id, photo_paths, caption, t):
    
    bot = Bot(token=bot_token)
    
    try:
    
        async with bot:
    
        media_list = [InputMediaPhoto(open(path, 'rb')) for path in photo_paths]
    
        await bot.send_media_group(chat_id=chat_id, media=media_list, caption=caption)
    
    except:
    
        print(f'Failed to send_photos - {t}')
    
async def post_to_telegram(t):
    
    try:
    
        bot_token = 'token'
    
        chat_id = 'chat_id'
    
        image_paths = ['tmp/img1','tmp/img2']
    
        caption = 'test sending multiple images in one post'
    
        await send_photos(bot_token, chat_id, image_paths, caption, t)
    
    except:
    
        print(f'Failed to post_to_telegram - {t} ')
    
        asyncio.ensure_future(post_to_telegram(t))

This works OK. However, if I try to do multiple posts using a for loop:
for t in ts:

asyncio.ensure_future(post_to_telegram(t))

Only some t's run successfully. Others just fails for some reason that I don't understand..
